# Input string was not in a correct format - wrong context is used

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

After changing ASP.NET Core Identity to use `int` rather than GUID (as per [this blog post)](https://robertwray.co.uk/blog/taking-the-guid-out-of-asp-net-core-identity) I am receiving the following error:

> ArgumentException: 395438ed-1cd9-4420-8a58-3f3b1f550bfc is not a valid
>   value for Int32. Parameter name: value
>   System.ComponentModel.BaseNumberConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext
>   context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserStoreBase.ConvertIdFromString(string id)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore.FindByIdAsync(string userId, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager.FindByIdAsync(string
>   userId)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager.GetUserAsync(ClaimsPrincipal
>   principal)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager.ValidateSecurityStampAsync(ClaimsPrincipal
>   principal)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SecurityStampValidator.ValidateAsync(CookieValidatePrincipalContext
>   context)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler.AuthenticateAsync()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext
>   context, string scheme)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
>   context)

when trying to query the database. Any clues as to why that might be?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per one of the [comments](https://robertwray.co.uk/blog/taking-the-guid-out-of-asp-net-core-identity#comment-4545) in the blog post:

> Thank you, this article was really useful. One gotcha for me was that
>   after swapping to use an int when I first loaded identity server again
>   I got an error on this line
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserStoreBase.ConvertIdFromString(string id).
>
> Turns out I had a cookie using the old guid format, simple fix was to
>   clear cookies.

The issue is that some of your previous logins were likely done when the ID was a GUID. You changed it to `int`, and so now it doesn't know how to handle the GUID any more. The simplest solution will be to delete your cookies, effectively logging you out and forcing you to login again (using `int` instead).

Comment: I can't believe you found this. Would have wasted the rest of my afternoon chasing this ghost. Thanks.

Comment: Wow! genius man, deleting the exists cookies is the clue